# SQLiteDB - what mean of the excute result?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am writing my app, with `sqlite`, when I insert data into the table(`t_deleteMsgs`)

[image]

In the `initData()`:

```
db = SQLiteDB.sharedInstance

let result = db.execute(sql: "create table if not exists t_deleteMsg(uid integer primary key, msg_userId varchar(20), msg_id varchar(20))")  // if not exists
print(result)
```

**Attention :**

The result print `1`, means success:

This is the `execute` method:

```
// Execute SQL with parameters and return result code
func execute(sql:String, parameters:[Any]?=nil)->CInt {
    var result:CInt = 0
    queue.sync() {
        if let stmt = self.prepare(sql:sql, params:parameters) {
            result = self.execute(stmt:stmt, sql:sql)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

And the `self.execute`:

```
private func execute(stmt:OpaquePointer, sql:String)->CInt {
    // Step
    var result = sqlite3_step(stmt)
    if result != SQLITE_OK && result != SQLITE_DONE {
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
        if let error = String(validatingUTF8:sqlite3_errmsg(self.db)) {
            let msg = "SQLiteDB - failed to execute SQL: \(sql), Error: \(error)"
            NSLog(msg)
        }
        return 0
    }
    // Is this an insert
    let upp = sql.uppercased()
    if upp.hasPrefix("INSERT ") {
        // Known limitations: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html
        let rid = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(self.db)
        result = CInt(rid)
    } else if upp.hasPrefix("DELETE") || upp.hasPrefix("UPDATE") {
        var cnt = sqlite3_changes(self.db)
        if cnt == 0 {
            cnt += 1
        }
        result = CInt(cnt)
    } else {
        result = 1
    }
    // Finalize
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
    return result
}
```

And after go in my vc and create the table, then insert data into table:

```
func saveDeleteMsgToDB(userId:String , deleteId:String) {

    let sql = "insert into t_deleteMsgs(msg_userId, msg_id) values('\(userId)', '\(deleteId)')"

    print("sql:\(sql)")
    // 通过封装的方法执行sql
    let result = db.execute(sql: sql)
    print(result)
}
```

Result: print the result: `2`. I don't know the `2` means what, you can see my `self.execute` method I post in the front, if is means insert success?

So, I pop the `vc`, then come in the `vc` again, the `vc` will invoke the `initDeleteArr()` again:

```
 func initDeleteArr() {

    let userStatic:UserStaticSwift = UserStaticSwift.sharedInstance()

    let data = db.query(sql: "select * from t_deleteMsgs where msg_userId = \(userStatic.userId)")  // here the data's count is 0.
    if data.count > 0 {

        let delete_msg = data[data.count - 1]
        print(delete_msg)
    }
}
```

In the `initDeleteArr()`:

> SQLiteDB - failed to prepare SQL: select * from t_deleteMsgs where msg_userId = d92c1ea9541c477fbed9135c28bc4e12, Error: no such column: d92c1ea9541c477fbed9135c28bc4e12

So, where is the issue here, if is I insert data fail?

Comment: On your screen I see *userId* field instead of *msg_userId*.

Comment: @Blady214, I am sorry for the low-grade error, can you see my update question ? I insert my data fail ?

Comment: your have to put ' around your id because it is not a numeric but a VARCHAR. So it would look like this `let data = db.query(sql: "select * from t_deleteMsgs where msg_userId = '\(userStatic.userId)'")`

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL expression is invalid: `select * from t_deleteMsgs where msg_userId = d92c1ea9541c477fbed9135c28bc4e12` because it will looks for column named d92c1ea9541c477fbed9135c28bc4e12. Escape this string with `'` and it should works:

`select * from t_deleteMsgs where msg_userId = 'd92c1ea9541c477fbed9135c28bc4e12'`,

so in your code:

```
let data = db.query(sql: "select * from t_deleteMsgs where msg_userId = '\(userStatic.userId)'")
```

Comment: i think your meant `'\(userStatic.userId)'`not `\'(userStatic.userId)'`. Because the second would not insert the value of the variable, it would insert '(userStatic.userId)' just as a String.